# Isolation unique name not being applied to html elements I add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

anyone seen any issues where razor code you write isn't given an isolation name which causes its isolated css to not be able to find it?

```html
<!--_Layout.cshtml-->
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><img src="~/img/Dimensions360_Logo_192x113.png" /></a>
```

```css
/*_Layout.cshtml.css*/
a.navbar-brand > img {
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

and the generated html is not putting the `b-u43b921rpo` isolation name on my `img`

yet the generated css does include that name

```css
a.navbar-brand > img[b-u43b921rpo] {
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see now this is by design:

> Scoped CSS only applies to HTML elements and not to Razor components or Tag Helpers, including elements with a Tag Helper applied, such as .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0